# Iterating through with PSObject in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to get the values of the properties of an [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) instance.

But it keeps giving me null exceptions

The code I am using is as follows.

```
var xs = PowerShell.Create()
        .AddScript("Get-ADComputer -Identity COM-PC-003$ -Properties * | select operatingsystem, accountexpires")
        .AddCommand("out-string");
Collection<PSObject> results = xs.Invoke();
//Console.WriteLine(xs);
foreach (var str in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str.Members["operatingsystem"].Value.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str.Properties["operatingsystem"].Value);
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you see any output if you type same commands in powershell?

Comment: Strings do **not** have `operatingsystem` property.

Comment: remove the `.AddCommand("out-string");`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this:

```
while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Hostname");
    var hn = Console.ReadLine();
    var xs = PowerShell.Create().AddScript(
               "$comp = Get-ADComputer -Identity " + hn +
               " -Properties *" + Environment.NewLine +
               "$obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject" +
               " -Property @{Host=$comp.operatingsystem;accountexpires = $comp.accountexpires}" +
               Environment.NewLine +
               "$obj1 = $obj | select -ExpandProperty Host ; $obj2 = $obj | select -ExpandProperty accountexpires ; $out = $obj1 + ' ; ' + $obj2 ; $out").AddCommand("out-string");
    Collection<PSObject> results = xs.Invoke();
    //Console.WriteLine(xs);
    foreach (var str in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You want to see only OS vers? If its true - enter H, also enter E for see accountexpires or A for see all info");
        ConsoleKeyInfo c = Console.ReadKey();

        if (c.KeyChar == 'H')
        {
             Console.WriteLine(str.ToString().Split(';')[0]);
             Console.ReadLine();
        }

        if (c.KeyChar == 'E')
        {
             Console.WriteLine(str.ToString().Split(';')[1]);
             Console.ReadLine();
        }

        if (c.KeyChar == 'A')
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```